# Set a file as "root"-user but using "user"-user's enviroment variables, program, alias etc

Tags: permissions, scripts, environment-variables

The question is a bit difficult to phrase but..

I am fairly new to Linux (running ubuntu 20.04), and I have script which requires "root" to run (it is in `/etc/network/if-up.d`). The problem is, I have as `user` defined some environment-variables in my `.profile` file, which the script needs to use.

How can I write the script/change its permissions such that it is run with `user`-settings (i.e variables, paths, alias, functions, programs etc.) but as root?

Comment: You could *source* your user's `.profile` from the script - but it's an ugly thing to do, security wise

Comment: It also seems ugly from the standpoint of maintainability. I have seen this before when a User wants Root to backup the system to a remote server, but using Users's ssh key. The correct solution there to create a new Root ssh key -- yes, it's fifteen minutes of hassle to generate and share the key...but six months later when you need to maintain the setup, doing it right (and documenting exactly what you did) saves hours of troubleshooting.

Comment: How would you then have multiple users running things as root, e.g if one user has one PYTHONPATH and another user has another. How would we be able to cope with that?  I find it a bit odd there isn't a "run-as <user>" permission just like "chown <user>" such that when a file is run, it is simply run as "user" but with the specified permissions